# named loops in Julia

Tags: loops, julia

in Fortran there are Named Loops but I have not found this function in Julia. Is there a way to do named loops? So that the compiler checks if the end statement corresponds to the correct loop start?
Thx for help

For example:

```
counting: for i = 1:5  
    println(i)  
end counting
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a feature, but, instead, the compiler tracks nested loops to allow nested end statements. In addition, there are break, continue, and and try/catch features of the language to do, generally more easily, what naming loops usually do in Fortran. Leaving out a nested end statement with nested loops will generate a syntax error by the compiler.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/index.html#man-loops-1

Comment: but how do I know, which end statement belongs to which loops instead of counting how much it is nested? If I have loops longer then a screen, I would need to go up and search all the time. So yeah Julia tracks that for every loop there is a corresponding end. What I want is readability in cases like

    end
    *stuff1*
    end
    end
    *stuff2*

So that I am able to immediately see if the stuff2 is at the correct position or for example outside the function(after the functions end).

Comment: What I used to do in C is comment my ending brackets. Lately I have an editor that marks all such statements with a narrow line bracket from 'for' to 'end' along the left hand side of the window, and this is usually enough to show where the missing end is. I agree that having the compiler error report potentially mark the code for a misplaced loop ending according to your label is a nice Fortran feature though :)